# handle page events in itext of page break

Tags: itext

i am using itext for generating pdf and want to know what happens behind the scene when an element exceeds the size of page.

i am using PdfPageEventHelper to get to know if a new page is added in this case.

resulting pdf shows a new page but don't trigger my functions for event such as onStartPage ,onEndPage.

Comment: Show us your code. There are plenty of examples around that prove that `onStartPage()` and `onEndPage()` are triggered. Take a look at the **Page events** section in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](https://leanpub.com/itext_so) for some examples.

Comment: i tried it again and found it working but still have a question about the difference between NEWPAGE and NEXTPAGE

Answer (score 0):

I am using `PdfPageEventHelper` and I don't experience any problem with it. When a new page is triggered, the `onEndPage()` method is called *before* a new page is initialized, and the `onStartPage()` method is called *after* the new page is initialized.

You can trigger a new page in your code like this:

```
document.newPage();
```

Or the `newPage()` method can be triggered implicitly, for instance when you add content using `document.add()` that exceeds the size of the page.

Your allegation that the functions such as `onEndPage()` and `onStartPage()` aren't triggered can't be verified. On the contrary: we have plenty of examples that prove otherwise, some of which are bundled in the book [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow.](https://leanpub.com/itext_so)

In the comments, you say that you have a question about the different between `NEWPAGE` and `NEXTPAGE`. This is a very strange question, as I don't know why you'd ever need these objects.

`Chunk.NEXTPAGE` is a special `Chunk` that is used internally by iText. It can be used to invoke the `newPage()` method by adding an object.

For instance:

```
document.add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);
```

is the equivalent of:

```
document.newPage();
```

The latter method is the preferred way to trigger a new page, the `NEXTPAGE` object is used internally in very specific use cases.

As for `Chunk.NEWPAGE`, that's merely a `String` (it's value is `"NEWPAGE"`). This `String` is the attribute key used to identify a `NEXTPAGE` chunk.

This belongs to the internal kitchen of iText. As an iText user, you shouldn't worry about it.